# Consulta con relaciones

Tags: mysql, eloquent, model, relaciones

Lo que pretendo hacer y no se como es traer dos relaciones de una relación con eloquent, suena confunso pero asi es como traigo una relacion de una relacion previa:

```
$surveys= Survey::where('id',$id)->with('surveyQuestions.answer')->get();
```

Lo que quiero traer son dos relaciones que se encuentran en surveyQuestions, en ese mismo arreglo, no solo a answer

Comment: Agrega tus modelos y te ayudamos